# How to shift elements to the left as much as possible? Prolog

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have a list with 4 elements [0,4,0,2] (Can be any arrangement). Each element in the list will move towards left. If an elements neighbor is zero so it can easily move towards the left. If the neighbor is a non zero number then it can not move towards left. (Example: [8,0,2,3] will become [8,2,3,0], and [0,4,0,2] will become [4,2,0,0])

Here is my current attempt:

```
shift_left([],_):-!.
shift_left([H1,H2|T],S):-
    H1=0,
    append(S,[H2|T],L1),
    write(L1),
    shift_left([H2|T],_).
shift_left([H1|T],_):-
    H1\=0,
    shift_left(T,[H1]).
```

My second attempt after looking at CapelliC's answer. It works great.

```
shift_left([],[]).
shift_left([H|T],S):-
    shift_left(T,Q),
    H=0,
    append(Q,[0],S).
shift_left([H|T],S):-
    shift_left(T,Q),
    H\=0,
    S=[H|Q].
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simpler solution - in the sense it's less technical - wrt Willem' answer, and make use of append/3, as your original code

```erlang
shift_left([],[]).
shift_left([H|T],S):-
    shift_left(T,Q),
    (   H=0
    ->  append(Q,[0],S)
    ;   S=[H|Q]
    ).
```

test

```erlang
?- maplist(shift_left,[[8,0,2,3],[0,4,0,2]],Ss).
Ss = [[8, 2, 3, 0], [4, 2, 0, 0]].
```

Comment: :-( the worst computational complexity answer; as a bonus, could fill up the stack because it prevents last call optimization. And to think that I was a little bit ashamed of what I wrote.

Comment: @TA_intern: sure, I know. Nevertheless, simplicity of code must be weighted in, specially when the asker (yet) doesn't know Prolog. And sincerely, I have bad memories trying to debug attributed variables solutions. Don't want to shift that to a Prolog newbie. Most of the time new people coming to Prolog is scared by the basic semantic, and then how to explain how useful is coroutining, tabling, etc...

Comment: I think I understand. If you don't like attributed variables (I guess you mean `dif/2`?) you can use `\=` or `\==`. But still a list is a list and "appending" means traversing the whole list.

Answer (score 5):

We can enumerate over the list, and each time we see a zero, we can push it on the list of elements to emit later when we reach the end of the list:

```
shift_left(L, R) :-
    shift_left(L, [], R).

shift_left([], Zs, Zs).
shift_left([H|T], Zs, [H|R]) :-
    dif(H, 0),
    shift_left(T, Zs, R).
shift_left([0|T], Zs, R) :-
    shift_left(T, [0|Zs], R).
```

This then give us:

```
?- shift_left([8,0,2,3], R).
R = [8, 2, 3, 0] ;
false.

?- shift_left([0,4,0,2], R).
R = [4, 2, 0, 0] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a more technical solution. It is basically the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64777326/14411997) but uses library predicates and does one extra traversal of the Not Zeros.

```
bubble_up_zeros(List, Result) :-
    partition(not_zero, List, Not_zeros, Zeros),
    append(Not_zeros, Zeros, Result).

not_zero(X) :- dif(X, 0).
```